# Why is the input prepend or text pushed into the next row in the Bootstrap form?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, line-breaks

Since the column sizing is relative, I assume it would fit everything into one row, especially with the prepend. I am including the relevant part of the HTML, along with my custom CSS styling in case it applies. I tried changing input display to inline, to no avail. Not sure what else may be causing this, I'm not that familiar with Bootstrap.

HTML

```
            <div class="products">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="rioVerde" style="border: 1px white solid" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Rio Verde Hot Sauce</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="border: 1px white solid">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">$8</span>
  </div>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" id="quantityVerde" aria-describedby="quantityVerde" placeholder="0" name="quantityVerde">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="rioVerde" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Diablo Rojo Hot Sauce</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" id="quantityVerde" aria-describedby="quantityVerde" placeholder="0" name="quantityVerde">
                  x $8.00
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="rioVerde" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Mango Bolero Hot Sauce</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" id="quantityVerde" aria-describedby="quantityVerde" placeholder="0" name="quantityVerde">
                  x $8.00
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="rioVerde" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">"Hot Like Me" Hot Sauce</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" id="quantityVerde" aria-describedby="quantityVerde" placeholder="0" name="quantityVerde">
                  x $8.00
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="rioVerde" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Pickled Red Cabbage</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" id="quantityVerde" aria-describedby="quantityVerde" placeholder="0" name="quantityVerde">
                  x $6.00
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

... CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}

body{
    background: rgb(252,230,214);
    background: linear-gradient(41deg, rgba(252,230,214,1) 0%, rgba(214,247,247,1) 100%);
    background-image: url("/images/bg1.jpg");
    background-position: fixed;
    background-repeat: none;
    background-size: cover;
}

#form {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.container-fluid{
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.display-3{
    color: white;
    margin: 10px auto 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card{
    background-color: rgba(55,55,55,0.5);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

label{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.products{
  margin: 50px 0;
}

input{
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `row` is set to use `display: flex`, but this only applies to it's direct children. Your input, prepend and the text are in another div (with class `col-sm-6`) so the flex properties are bring applied to them.

You can add the flex property to the inputs' parent (i.e. the `col-sm-6` divs) to make this work as follows:

```
.form-group > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This selects the direct children of the `form-group`s that are `div`s, but you could add a class to the input container to make it easier (and less prone to picking up the wrong elements).

You will then need to add any space you want between the input and its prepend and text, e.g.:

```
.products .form-group input {
  display: inline-block; 
  /* add space after the input to separate it from the text */
  margin-right: 5px; 
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.products .form-group div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.products .form-group input {
  display: inline-block; 
  /* add space after the input to separate it from the text */
  margin-right: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="products">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="rioVerde" style="border: 1px white solid" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Rio Verde Hot Sauce</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border: 1px white solid">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">$8</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" id="quantityVerde" aria-describedby="quantityVerde" placeholder="0" name="quantityVerde">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="rioVerde" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Diablo Rojo Hot Sauce</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" id="quantityVerde" aria-describedby="quantityVerde" placeholder="0" name="quantityVerde"> x $8.00
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="rioVerde" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Mango Bolero Hot Sauce</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" id="quantityVerde" aria-describedby="quantityVerde" placeholder="0" name="quantityVerde"> x $8.00
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="rioVerde" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">"Hot Like Me" Hot Sauce</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" id="quantityVerde" aria-describedby="quantityVerde" placeholder="0" name="quantityVerde"> x $8.00
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="rioVerde" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Pickled Red Cabbage</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" id="quantityVerde" aria-describedby="quantityVerde" placeholder="0" name="quantityVerde"> x $6.00
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```